# Fatal error: Could not load sails

Tags: mysql, sails.js

Whenever i run a sails-db-migrate command

> grunt db:migrate:create --name add-some-fooz --force

i am getting this error

```
Warning: Task "add-some-fooz" not found. Used --force, continuing.

Running "db:migrate:create" (db:migrate) task
Fatal error: Could not load sails
```

Comment: Any luck finding the problem? I have the same issue

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem. After I add `=` after `name` it goes without errors:

```
grunt db:migrate:create --name=add-some-fooz --force
```